# Solving $(x^3 -3x)^2 = x+2$: is this a problem with WolframAlpha?

Tags: polynomials, wolfram-alpha

$f(x)=(x^3 -3x)^2 - x-2$

Well, I was trying to find the roots of this polynomial of degree $6$ and, after a look at
[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E3+-3x)%5E2+-x-2+%3D+0) I noticed something strange. According to Wolfram, there are $3$ real roots and $3$ complex non-real roots. How is this possible, since, because of Conjugate Complex Root Theorem, there always have to be an even number of them?

I can see that the plot shows $6$ intersections with the $x$-axis, then probably this is a problem with Wolfram indeed...

Comment: Even, if an expression contains non-real terms, the result of the expression can be real. The given polynomial factors into $3$ polynomials with degrees $1$, $2$ and $3$. So, Wolfram alpha gives the exact solutions, if you ask it for the approximate values, you should get the decimal expansions of the roots.

Comment: The polynomial has the rational root $x=2$ and the quintic resulting after the $x-2$ factor is taken out can be further factored, so there is no need to rely on WA for the nature of the roots. And, as you noted, the first big red flag is that a real polynomial cannot have an *odd* number of complex non-real roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the solutions are computed with floating point arithmetic and there are some rounding errors.
The imaginary parts are $10^{-16}$ and $5\cdot 10^{-17}.$

(Maple gives the roots as exact radicals, but if you convert to floating point you
get imaginary parts of order $10^{-d},$ where $d$ is the number of digits in the computation.)